# Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a CVS made from an excel file, but is not working, i'm receiving the following error ->  Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.

Follow the table structure

[image]

Follow the cvs file content

[image]

Do I need to have an id field in the csv file? Since its auto incremented, do i need to add it?

Follow is the import config of phpmyadmin

[image]

Another doubt, for each entry of mysql table, i would like to add an timestamp, is the configuration right? For every entry of the table, a timestamp will be added?

Regards

Comment: remove the header row and include the id column

Comment: I think i solved the problem, there was some excel formulas on the CSV file. After I removed the formulas the import worked, except for the timestamp, i didn't add automatically, i had do add it manually in excel csv before importing the file.